# CakePHP shell: Switch CAKE_ENV on the Go

Tags: php, cakephp, console-application, cakephp-3.0, server-side-scripting

I have a little problem in here. I'm new at cakephp and now have to developing a cakephp shell script to saving data into its database. The problem is, I work on default environment and need to save data into another environment. I'm using this code to switch environment:

```
ConnectionManager::alias($env, 'default');
```

It seems good since I've got right output when try to get database.

```
$this->out($datasource->config()['database']);
```

And then I load my model:

```
$model = $this->Model;
```

But It's load the model data from `default` environment. Is my approach wrong? Or, there is another method to switch environment on the go with cakephp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work just fine, and a quick test shows that it does. You'd probably have to show a little more context, but I guess you are loading the model (what you're showing there isn't *loading* but *accessing*) before the connection alias is being created, hence the model will use the original connection that it received when it has been instantiated.

So either make sure that you *load* the model afterwards, respectively that you create the alias before the model is being loaded (that is when `TableRegistry::get()` is being invoked), or change the connection of the specific model on the fly in case applicable:

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get($env);
$model->setConnection($connection); // use connection($connection) in CakePHP < 3.4
```

Comment: thank you very much. It's worked! I need two days work on this. Thanks a lot. :D